# Disable opt-in e-mails for joining groups

Tags: civimail, webform-civicrm, groups, confirmation

I use a custom Drupal Webform for contacts to join groups. This happens within a restricted environment, the user is logged in and managing his/her own profile behind a password. I don't want any e-mail to be sent.

When a group is marked as 'mailing list', CiviCRM sends out a confirmation mail. If a group is marked both 'mailing list' and 'access control', no e-mail is sent.

I've unchecked 'Enable Double Opt-in for Profile Group(s) field ' in the CiviMail component. Doesn't seem to make a difference (this is not a 'profile groups checkbox' as per the description there i think - its a webform).

So I'm about to check the 'access control' for a dozen of groups, only to disable the e-mail confirmation. What am I doing wrong ? :-)

Comment: According to this http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6818/what-does-group-type-mailing-list-do?rq=1 I could also uncheck the mailing list box in my case ...

Comment: Unfortunately Andrew Hunt mentions there that that is a bug, not a feature

Comment: .. and the bug has been fixed in 4.7.10, at least. so that's not an option anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You probably saw this but there is a second setting that deals with Double Opt-In - but since you only referred to one, the other one is

> Enable Double Opt-in for Profiles which use the "Add to Group" setting 
>   When CiviMail is enabled and a profile uses the "Add to Group" setting, users who complete the profile form will receive a confirmation email. They must respond (opt-in) before they are added to the group.

Also at this path - civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/mailing?reset=1

Comment: Thanks, saw that. I'm not using a profile, I'm using a Drupal Webform.

Comment: i think you should note that in the question, and add webform-civicrm tag - may help

Answer (score 1):

You may have been here / tested already, but I believe if you are in Drupal Webform, there is another 'confirm subscription' configuration under the 'Additional Options' tab which is checked by default.